# Generating SQL "IN" clauses: how to safely handle input + empty value lists?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sql-injection

In my Python code I often find myself doing the following (using DB-API):

```
yValues = pickInterestingValuesOfY()

sql = "..." # includes a clause stating that "y must be in yValues"

c.execute(sql, yValues)
```

In the end, the SQL being executed could be something as simple as

```
SELECT x FROM table1 WHERE y IN (1,2,3);
```

The issue is that the set of possible values for y (1,2,3) is determined at run-time.

I have two concerns:

1. generate valid SQL in the case where yValues is empty ('WHERE y IN ()' is invalid SQL)
2. watch out for sql injection if the values come from an untrusted source

To address (2) I must let the DB-API actually insert the yValues into the SQL statement. So I ended up with the following convoluted solution:

```
def inClause(columnName, values):

    if len(values):
         placeHolders = ','.join( ['%s'] * len(values) )
         sql = "%s IN (%s)" % (columnName, placeHolders)
    else: 
         sql = "FALSE"
    return "(%s)" % sql

# get a db-api cursor called c
c.execute("SELECT x FROM table1 WHERE %s;" % inClause('y', yValues), yValues)
```

which seems to correctly address both concerns above. However, I cannot believe this clunky solution is what it takes.

How do you handle such queries? Am I missing a more elegant way to do this?

I am not looking for an ORM.

(I am using MySQL, so if there is some magic mysql non-standard switch that silently accepts 'WHERE y IN ()' as valid just let me know and concern (1) will be taken care of.)

Comment: +1 Good question, I have been wondering that myself. I use sqlite, though---which does accept an empty tuple (as in `WHERE y IN ()`), so I'm surprised that MySQL doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There's no pretty way to do it. DB-API does not have any specification for handling sequences in this manner.

Comment: Not really. At least `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 0` is an acceptable generic way to generate an empty record set for MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

For the in clause, just always include a value that won't be in the list (e.g. a negative integer).

Comment: Similarly, rather than a value (where the column datatype could change down the road), it works with apostrophe's. ie. `IN ('')`

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can do this:

```
SELECT x FROM table1 WHERE y IN (SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 0);
```

`DUAL` is a virtual table which is born for this purpose. It's suitable for selecting data that doesn't require a table. And the `WHERE 0` clause ensures that no record is returned from the subquery.

In short, `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 0` is a perfect substitution for an empty list.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought that could be more like a global solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Don't generate your own SQL.

Use SQLAlchemy.  It does this for you.